Share specific view of a Microsoft List
Is there a way of sharing specific view of Microsoft List (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/microsoft-lists)?
I've tried to "Share" the list when specific view was active, but it always opens either the full list either last opened view, but not the one I had open.


The links to specific views work now, after recreating the list in a new SharePoint site.
The original list was probably corrupted.
